# Trying to open folder with python

Tags: python, directory

I'm making a school project, and I wrote some code so that I could open the folder with the results.

```
script_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
script_dir = os.path.split(script_path)[0]
rel_path = "Imagens-prontas/"
self.cur_dir = os.getcwd()
abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)
os.system(f"start {abs_file_path}")
sleep(1)
```

but when I but the program files on the advanced installer and then try to use the function I just get an error:
[image: error]

Comment: You have spaces in the file path. Try `os.system(f'start "{abs_file_path}"')` - so the path is quoted.

Comment: @tdelaney kind of worked it should have been os.open(f'start "{abs_file_path}"'), thanks man I've been 20min trying to understand why wasn't working

Comment: "kind of worked"? @tdelaney gave the exact answer. -- I'm sure it's *not* `os.open` because that opens files for reading/writing, it does not run commands.

Comment: I forgot to say I actually used this instead os.startfile(f'"{abs_file_path}"')